# RBAC Auth Issue API - Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, authorization, rbac, azure-rbac

I have been trying to use RBAC checkAccess endpoint and I am receiving a 500 error - InternalServerErrror. This is what I tried:

```
var rbacUri ="https://api-dogfood.resources.windows-int.net/subscriptions/{subId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/checkaccess?api-version=2018-09-01-preview"

var request = new RbacCheckRequest
{
    Subject = new RbacCheckSubject
    {
        Attributes = new() { { "ObjectId", objectId } }
    },
    Actions = new[]
    {
        new RbacCheckAction
        {
            Id = "Microsoft.Authorization/checkAccess/action"
        }
    },
    Resource = new RbacCheckResource
    {
        Id = "/subscriptions/"+subscriptionId
    }
};
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(rbacUri, request, cancellationToken)
```

Please help. Is there any other way to verify if a certain object id has permission to perform a certain action?

I have verified the `objectid` has permissions via `Microsoft.Authorization/permissions`. But this gives all permissions for a certain `objectid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed adding object id in attributes field under resource property, once I added it, it worked